# JSONException PHP Android

Tags: php, android

can you help me with this? 
So I was looking for getting data from remote database. 
I've downloaded and installed WAMP server and connect to remote database, I've added some rows ecc...
Working with PhP storm, I created script that seems to be work, it shows all that I need. 
The problem is the logcat, could you tell how can i fix it?

```
    11-07 20:12:21.139 17619-17619/com.example.arnold.itsosgadda E/log_data: Comunicazione n.129  <a href="http://www.itsosgadda.it/comunicazioni/pubbliche/2015-16%20Comunicazione%20129%20Uscita%20didattica%203B%20museo%20del%20computer%20Fornovo.pdf">Download<br>
11-07 20:12:21.139 17619-17619/com.example.arnold.itsosgadda W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value Comunicazione of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
11-07 20:12:21.149 17619-17619/com.example.arnold.itsosgadda W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
11-07 20:12:21.149 17619-17619/com.example.arnold.itsosgadda W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:96)
11-07 20:12:21.149 17619-17619/com.example.arnold.itsosgadda W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:108)
11-07 20:12:21.149 17619-17619/com.example.arnold.itsosgadda W/System.err:     at com.example.arnold.itsosgadda.CommunicationsActivity.connect(CommunicationsActivity.java:59)
11-07 20:12:21.149 17619-17619/com.example.arnold.itsosgadda W/System.err:     at com.example.arnold.itsosgadda.CommunicationsActivity.onCreate(CommunicationsActivity.java:36)
11-07 20:12:21.149 17619-17619/com.example.arnold.itsosgadda W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
11-07 20:12:21.149 17619-17619/com.example.arnold.itsosgadda W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
11-07 20:12:21.149 17619-17619/com.example.arnold.itsosgadda W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2199)
11-07 20:12:21.149 17619-17619/com.example.arnold.itsosgadda W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2285)
11-07 20:12:21.149 17619-17619/com.example.arnold.itsosgadda W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138)
11-07 20:12:21.149 17619-17619/com.example.arnold.itsosgadda W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1236)
11-07 20:12:21.149 17619-17619/com.example.arnold.itsosgadda W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-07 20:12:21.149 17619-17619/com.example.arnold.itsosgadda W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
11-07 20:12:21.149 17619-17619/com.example.arnold.itsosgadda W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5061)
11-07 20:12:21.149 17619-17619/com.example.arnold.itsosgadda W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-07 20:12:21.149 17619-17619/com.example.arnold.itsosgadda W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-07 20:12:21.159 17619-17619/com.example.arnold.itsosgadda W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
11-07 20:12:21.159 17619-17619/com.example.arnold.itsosgadda W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:603)
11-07 20:12:21.159 17619-17619/com.example.arnold.itsosgadda W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

## Here my PHP script

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Arnol'd
 * Date: 07.11.2015
 * Time: 15:27
 */
$username = 'app';
$password = '4826159g';
$hostname = 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx';
$database = 'app_db';
$conn = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $database);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed:" . $conn->connect_error);
}
$sql = "select * from push";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row["push_name"] . '  <a href="'.$row['link'].'">' . 'Download' . "<br>";

    }
}
else{
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

## Here my java android code

```
package com.example.arnold.itsosgadda;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class CommunicationsActivity extends Activity {
    private String jsonResult;
    private String url = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx/config.php";
    private ListView listView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.communications_news_layout);
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        connect();

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        assert actionBar != null;
        actionBar.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#ffeb3b")));
    }

    private void connect() {
        String data;
        List<String> listData = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listData);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        try {
            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
            request.setHeader("Accept","application/json");
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            Log.e("log_data", data);
            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(data);
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String name = obj.optString("push_name");
                    String link = obj.getString("link");
                    Log.e("log_data", name);

                    listData.add(name);
                    listData.add(link);
                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    /*final CommunicationsActivity activity = this;
    final String url = "http://www.itsosgadda.it/index.php/comunicazioni-pubbliche";
    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        assert actionBar != null;
        actionBar.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#ffeb3b")));
        //Shows me status bar progress

        setContentView(R.layout.communications_news_layout);
        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        //Enables JS
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        //noinspection deprecation
        webView.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(FAR);
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                activity.setTitle(R.string.loading_progress);
                activity.setProgress(progress * 100);
                if (progress == 100) {
                    activity.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
                }
            }
        });

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                // Handle the error
                Log.i("WEB_VIEW_COMMUNICATIONS", "Error code: " + errorCode);
                super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        });
        webView.loadUrl(url);
    }*/

}
```

Comment: `You don't have permission to access /config.php` check your server config or paste your server config

Comment: Now the problem is other....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in your json file which is generated by the php. Particular android thinks that the pdf link you are feeding it is not a JSONArray, maybe it is a json object? It would be advisable to test your json http://jsonlint.com/ and post your whole json respone here.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you shouldn't publish your IP. And talking about your problem, you are receiving an HTML page that can't be converted to JSON. It can be an error or anything else, try to print the received response before trying to convert it to JSON and probably you will know what is happening

Comment: I've got another type of problem

Comment: Why are you returning HTML in your PHP? If you want JSON, create an array fill it inside the while loop giving the elements a name and value and after the loop json encode it. If you want HTML don't decode it to JSON in your client

Comment: You can create an HTML format String in your JSON value, but you need to give it a key name and then encode the array to JSON